# Freestanding Pantry removal walls, Load bearing?

Tags: walls, load-bearing, load

[image]

I have no floor plans for the home. This is a single story, non-basement home. It was built with a freestanding pantry in the middle of the room. Naturally we want to open it to increase traffic flow and have zero visual obstructions.

Drywall is mostly removed and each corner is a set of 2x4s in an L configurations. There is extra framing around where the door was, but even the framing is not laminated beams, just 2x4s.

The rule of perpendicular vs. parallel poses the challenge since this is a four sided freestanding box... two sides have to be parallel...but do they have to be load bearing?

Red lines on image above are joists. Green line is a beam.

[image: IMAGES]

Comment: Kind of odd place for a pantry,  small for load bearing except at that point area, unless using it as a support post for a beam holding up ceiling joists.  Would check attic if possible.  Any other odd things or walls inline of the pantry walls?

Comment: Is it near/at centre line of house?

Comment: it is toward center of house. There is no beam leading from it through attic to roof. Nearest wall is the small wall next to the fridge. There is a 3 foot span between that wall and the corner of the pantry, all other walls are significantly farther away.

Comment: In general, there is no reason for the pantry to be load-bearing. You can check the joists near/away from the pantry and the joist sit right on its sidewalls, if all joists are the same size, then this is not a load-bearing structure.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the attic joists and mark the location of the pantry?

Comment: The construction of the header over the pantry door indicates that that wall (in particular) isn't load bearing.

Comment: Joists run from kitchen to front door (in before picture) there is a large beam that runs perpendicular to the joists and it's roughly 2 feet from the pantry itself (right next to the air exchange seen in the picture. I can't see due to the insulation in the attic, but I would assume any tied in joists would tie in at the support beam itself... which is what makes me think the pantry isn't load bearing, but I'm a newbie.

Comment: I would tend to agree with your assessment of that beam, @user144558, that the pantry is _not_ load bearing. **However**, I am not an engineer and don't have enough construction experience to state that confidently. The updated drawing does help quite a bit. Also, for future reference, including all the pics is good. Including them in one single montage that cannot be enlarged much is a bit of a pain, though. You can post multiple images, or upload them to imgur.com and post a link here and someone will embed them for you.

Comment: good update with pictures. As @FreeMan writes: the header above the pantry door suggests that wall is *not* load bearing. Remains the pantry back wall: what's above it in the attic, is there a roof irregularity (extra load point)? Can you take a picture in the attic showing the joists? Otherwise poke a hole into the ceiling and take a pic showing whether joists are continuous over the pantry back wall's top plate, terminating only at beam.